# IS it a good practice to generate Url Like Below format in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url

IS it a good practice to generate Url Like Below format in MVC?

e.g- ProjectName/Admin/Admin/Edit?customerID=3

Answer (score 0):

What would be the concern with it?  I don't see any issue provided you had the necessary underlying security to prevent abuse.  So wrap the controller with proper authority and possibly have the admin in a seperate Area from the bulk of the app.

Comment: @kunguFuMaster Problem is url,this url may cause security issue also in plain ASP.net We use such url pattern when we pass data through querystring.here it ia an MVC Architecture,so will it cause any issue because i don't see any such kind of url pattern in Default MVC URLS.Yours suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I am just getting that you are decreasing my reputation count but not able to answer.